# Where is the maximum of the product of two logistic curves?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I've got  an asymmetric peak-like function $y(x) = y_1(x)y_2(x)$,
where $y_1(x) = 1 / (1 + f_1(x)) =  1 / ( 1 + e^{( -r_1(x-x_1))})$ is an increasing logistic function
and   $y_2(x) = 1 / (1 + f_2(x)) = 1 / ( 1 + e^{( -r_2*(x_2-x))})$ is a decreasing logistic function
with steepness parameters $r_1 > 0$ not equal to $r_2 > 0$ and
half-height points $x_1$, $x_2$.
The problem is: I can't express the $x$ coordinate of the maximum point of $y(x)$ using the 4 parameters above. The result should be $x_0 = F( x_1, x_2, r_1, r_2 ) $.
Is it ever possible to find it symbolically?

All I've found so far is:

1. an equation for $x_0$ which I couldn't solve:
   $y_1(x_0)f_1(x_0)r_1 = y_2(x_0)f_2(x_0)r_2$;
2. limits for $x_0$:

   2a)   $x_0 = ( x_1 r_1 + x_2 r_2 ) / (r_1 + r_2)$
   if $x_2 - x_1$ is "large enough" (i.e., "the peak is wide enough")

   2b)   $x_0 = (x_1 + x_2) / 2$
   if $r_2 = r_1$ (an evident case)
   2c)   $x_0 = x_2$
   if $r_2$ is greater than $r_1$ and $x_1 - x_2$ is "large enough" (i.e. "the peak has formally negative width") — this generally means that $x_0$ sticks to the center of the steeper multiple.

The question is: how to express $x_0$ (the maximum of $y(x)$) in terms of $r_1, r_2, x_1, x_2$ in general?
Is it possible at all?

Comment: I really do apologize for unformatted formulae...

Comment: ARA, thank you very much for editing

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $y(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. So, the maximum of the positive function $y$ is attained at a critical point of $y$. Such a critical point $x$ is a root of the equation
$$g(u):=g_{r,s,c}(u):=s e^{-s c} e^{r u}-r e^{-s u}+(s-r) e^{-s c},$$
where $r:=r_1$, $s:=r_2$, $u:=x-x_1$, and $c:=x_2-x_1$.

Clearly, $g$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,\infty)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. So, there is a unique root $u_{r,s,c}:=g^{-1}(0)=g_{r,s,c}^{-1}(0)$ of $g$. Thus, the maximum of $y$ is attained at the point
$$x_{r,s,c}:=u_{r,s,c}+x_1=g_{r,s,c}^{-1}(0)+x_1.$$

> It is extremely unlikely that $x_{r,s,c}$ is an elementary function of $(r,s,c,x_1)=(r_1,r_2,x_2-x_1,x_1)$ if $r\ne s$.

Indeed, consider just the special case when $r=4$, $s=1$, and $c=\ln2$. Then, with $z:=e^u$, the equation $g_{r,s,c}(u)=0$ becomes the algebraic equation
\begin{equation}
P(z):=z^5-3z-8=0 \tag{1}\label{1}   
\end{equation}
for real $z>0$. Mathematica cannot do anything even with this particular case:

[image]

---

> But this should not be a problem, since $g_{r,s,c}^{-1}$ is easy to analyze -- almost as easy to analyze as, say, the inverse hyperbolic functions.

---

It is also easy to compute $x_{r,s,c}$ numerically with a given degree of accuracy:

[image]

---

Let us now show (with the help from [Kevin Casto's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442600/can-the-positive-root-of-this-polynomial-be-expressed-elementarily#comment1142270_442600) and [Alexandre Eremenko's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442617/36721)) that -- modulo Schanuel's conjecture -- the positive root of equation \eqref{1} cannot be expressed elementarily, in the sense that it is not in the smallest field $EL$ of complex numbers closed under $\exp$ and $\log$ -- see the Definition on p. 3 of [Timothy Chow's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9805045v1).

Indeed, as noted on p. 5 of Timothy Chow's paper, "if Schanuel's conjecture
is true, then our notion of a 'closed-form algebraic number' coincides with the usual one,
i.e., solvability in radicals."

In turn, on p. 25 of [Ritt's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501211-X/) we find this: "Summarizing the foregoing results, we see that the only polynomials of prime degree whose inverses can be expressed in terms of radicals are those of the forms $a(w+b)^n+c$ and $af_n(bw+c)+d$, where $\cos nu=f_n(\cos u)$." (Note that Ritt only considers irreducible polynomials.)

In our case, the polynomial $P(z)=z^5-3z-8$ is irreducible and of degree $n=5$. So, here $f_n(t)=t (5 - 20 t^2 + 16 t^4)$.
Expanding $a(z+b)^5+c$ and equating the resulting coefficient of $z^4$ to that of $P(z)$, we see that then necessarily $b=0$, so that $z^5-3z-8=az^5+c$ for all $z$, a contradiction. Similarly, expanding $af_5(bz+c)+d$ and equating the resulting coefficient of $z^4$ to that of $P(z)$, we see that then necessarily $c=0$, and then necessarily $b=0$, so that $z^5-3z-8=d$ for all $z$, a contradiction.

Thus indeed, modulo Schanuel's conjecture, the positive root of equation \eqref{1} cannot be expressed elementarily. $\quad\Box$

---

**Update:** According to the latest [answer by Timothy Chow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442656/36721), the provision "modulo Schanuel's conjecture" can now be removed. Thus, my previously highlighted opinion that "It is extremely unlikely that $x_{r,s,c}$ is an elementary function of $(r,s,c,x_1)=(r_1,r_2,x_2-x_1,x_1)$ if $r\ne s$" is now completely justified.

Comment: Iosif Pinelis, thank you for a quick response. Agree, it's easy to find $x_0$ numerically and I have done it in some other programming language. The remaining question is just about beauty, not number :-) So, your answer is: "chances are that no symbolic solution can be written". Pity.

Comment: @newbie000 : Here is the "beauty": $g_{r,s,c}^{-1}(0)+x_1$. Is it really substantially less beautiful than, say, $\tanh^{-1}((s-r) e^{-s c})$?

Comment: @newbie000 : Also, my answer is not "chances are that no symbolic solution can be written". Rather, the answer is that (i) the chances that the solution is an elementary function seem extremely close to zero but (ii) that is really not a problem, because the solution is about as easy to analyze and compute as elementary functions.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: @newbie000 : It is now shown rigorously that, modulo Schanuel's conjecture, the maximizer cannot be expressed elementarily. 
As for Schanuel’s conjecture, as noted in the linked paper by Timothy Chow, "it implies many famous theorems and conjectures about transcendental numbers [... On the other hand,] A proof of Schanuel’s conjecture would be big news, although at present it seems to be out of reach."

Comment: @newbie000 : The provision "modulo Schanuel's conjecture" is now removed. Thus, my previously highlighted opinion that "It is extremely unlikely that $x_{r,s,c}$ is an elementary function of $(r,s,c,x_1)=(r_1,r_2,x_2-x_1,x_1)$ if $r\ne s$" is now completely justified.

Comment: @newbie000 : Do you have a further response to the updated answer?