# Can the positive root of this polynomial be expressed elementarily?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, galois-theory

> For each real $A>0$, let $x_A$ denote the positive root $x$ of the polynomial $x^5-3x-A$. Is the function $(0,\infty)\ni A\mapsto x_A$ elementary?

<s>[I am using this [definition of elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#Basic_examples), except for the algebraic functions mentioned there.]</s>

*Edit:* After the edifying answer by [Timothy Chow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442656/36721), I would like to clarify the use of the term *elementary functions* in this context just as  Timothy Chow suggested: "the functions that can be expressed using some finite combination of constant functions, the identity function, $\exp$, $\log$, composition, and arithmetic operations".

Comment: Assuming Schanuel's conjecture (and a specific defn of elementary function), no: see T Chow's "What is a closed-form number?"

Comment: Using Wikipedia's definition, every constant function is elementary, so every real number is a value of such a function. It also includes all algebraic functions, so the answer to the latter question is also yes.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Your post does not contain ANY definition. It refers to Wikipedia, which also does not contain any definition.

Comment: Do we allow complex numbers, so for example $\arctan x$ can be written in terms of logarithms?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Yes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe that the class of functions that Iosif Pinelis is interested in is what I would call *exponential-logarithmic functions* or *EL functions*; that is, they are the functions that can be expressed using some finite combination of constant functions, the identity function, $\exp$, $\log$, composition, and arithmetic operations (${+}{-}{\times}{\div}$). Some authors call this class of functions *elementary functions*, but that term is now more commonly used in a different sense, which includes algebraic functions. But Iosif Pinelis explicitly says he does not want to include all algebraic functions.

[Alexandre Eremenko's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442617) cites Ritt, which shows that the function in question is not expressible using radicals only.  However, as [Kevin Casto comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442600/can-the-positive-root-of-this-polynomial-be-expressed-elementarily#comment1142413_442617), this result does not immediately answer the question of whether the function is an EL function.

[Kevin Casto's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442650) cites a result of mine to show that the answer to [a version of] Iosif Pinelis's question is negative, but conditional on Schanuel's conjecture. So it is natural to ask if we can avoid assuming Schanuel's conjecture.

The answer is yes.  The reference I usually cite is *Abel's Theorem in Problems and Solutions*, by V. B. Alekseev, Kluwer, 2004.  Specifically, see the Appendix by Khovanskii. There are various theorems in this appendix which yield the desired negative answer, but perhaps the most explicit statement can be found in Section A.8:

> If an algebraic equation is not solvable by radicals then it remains non-solvable using the logarithm, the exponentials, and the other meromorphic functions in the complex plane.

Comment: I'm confused about the final clause of your quote. Can't you solve the quintic with elliptic functions?

Comment: @KevinCasto Good question; I haven't paid attention to the "meromorphic" part of this result before. The original paper is [Topological obstructions to the representability of functions by quadratures](https://web.archive.org/web/20230313232643/http://www.math.toronto.edu/~askold/1995-J-Dyn-Cont-Syst-1.pdf), J. Dynam. Control Sys. 1 (1995). Page 115 seems relevant.

Comment: I think the short answer may be that the quintic can be solved in terms of elliptic *integrals*, but these have logarithmic singularities and hence are not meromorphic.

Comment: @TimothyChow : Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to read the sources cited by you. Sorry for being slow. This area is completely new to me.

Comment: @TimothyChow Ah fair enough, I had found some post that wrote out formulas, but I didn't scrutinize them enough to realize that. So I guess the idea is that the only non-meromorphic function you throw in is log

Comment: @TimothyChow do these results answer some of the questions you have raised in "What is a closed-form number"?

Comment: @AlonAmit No. Those questions were about EL numbers. The results mentioned here are about EL functions, and were (mostly) already known at the time I wrote my paper.

Answer (score 6):

In Timothy Chow's "[What is a closed-form number?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210614034906/http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)" (*Amer. Math. Monthly* 1999), it is shown in Theorem 2 that Schanuel's conjecture implies that the roots of a polynomial with non-solvable Galois group are not in the subfield of "EL numbers" (the subfield generated by 0, field operations, exp, and log).

If your function were elementary, then its value at any integer would be an EL number. Taking $a = 8$, we that there is one real root, so complex conjugation swaps two pairs of complex roots, and Cauchy's theorem says there is a 5-cycle in the Galois group. Together these generate at least $A_5$, so the Galois group is not solvable, and thus not an EL number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please detail it (reproducing specific known statements and explicitly connecting them to the posted question), so that users (me included) could understand and appreciate this better?

Comment: Thank you for these details. Could you please further detail this: "Cauchy's theorem says there is a 5-cycle in the Galois group"?

Comment: "If your function were elementary, then its value at any integer would be an EL number." With the definitions provided this is not the case, since all constant functions are elementary.

Comment: @Wojowu Good point. One would have to redefine EL functions to exclude arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify your exact definition of elementary functions. With some definition, this is proved in the paper
of J. F. Ritt,
On algebraic functions which can be expressed in terms of radicals.
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (1922), no. 1, 21–30.

Comment: What specific ambiguities do see in the definition of elementary functions used in my post?

Comment: I don't think Ritt's paper proves that the roots could not be written as some composition of exp, log, and field operations

Comment: @KevinCasto : I think you are right. However, I think it is shown by referenced by you [Timothy Chow}(http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9805045v1) that "[modulo Schanuel's conjecture] our notion of a 'closed-form algebraic number' coincides with the usual one, i.e., solvability in radicals." So, modulo Schanuel's conjecture, the combination of Ritt's and Chow's results gives what is needed. Anyway, I would appreciate it if you could expand your previous comment into a formal answer.

Comment: @Kevin Castro: you are right. But log, exp etc are useless in representing an ALGEBRAIC function.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : "log, exp etc are useless in representing an ALGEBRAIC function." Useless in what sense and why?

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point, let us find out the real solutions of the fifth degree polynomial equation $x^5-3 \cdot x-a=0$ and then let us check it out if there is only one positive root for $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
The answer is clearly affirmative, so we have that $a=\frac{12}{5}\cdot \sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{5}} \Rightarrow x=\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{135}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{9 \cdot \sqrt[4]{60}-7 \cdot \sqrt[4]{135}}}-\frac{1}{3}\cdot \sqrt[3]{9 \cdot \sqrt[4]{60} -7 \cdot \sqrt[4]{135}} \approx 1.4527$.
Now, let us find out if it is possible to quickly answer to the main question. The key here is to look at the quintic equation $x^5 + b \cdot x+ c = 0$ (where we have $b:=-3$ and $c:=-a$) as a solvable equation expressed in the Bring–Jerrard form (see [Solvable quintic equations with commensurable coeffiecients](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369502)) if and only if $b = 0$ (and this is clearly not the case, since $-3 \neq 0$) or $-3=\frac{5 \cdot \mu^4 \cdot (4 \cdot \nu + 3)}{\nu^2+1} \wedge -a=\frac{4 \cdot \mu^5 \cdot (2 \cdot \nu + 1)}{4 \cdot \nu + 3}$ for $\mu, \nu$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$.
Now, since our Bring–Jerrard quintic is solvable if and only if $-3=\frac{5 \cdot \mu^4 \cdot (4 \cdot \nu + 3)}{\nu^2+1}$ can be solved for both $\mu$ and $\nu$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that this is not the case (since the only two solutions are $(\mu:=\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{5}}, \nu:=-2)$ and $(\mu:=-\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{5}}, \nu:=-2)$ so that $\mu \not\in \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A few questions: (i) What do you mean by "a solvable equation"? (ii) Where do you get your "if and only if" statement in the middle of your answer from? I do not see it in the paper you linked. (iii) What do you mean by "the only two solutions" in your last sentence and how do you prove that claim?

Comment: You are welcome. Answers: (i) Solvable by radicals (I mean, the famous result by Abel and Galois at the beginning of the XIX century concerning the fact that it is not possible to provide a general formula able to solve all the quintic equations); (ii) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function $\rightarrow$ "Quintics in Bring–Jerrard form" $\rightarrow$ line 3; (iii) I just solved the stated equation $-3= \frac{5 \mu^4 (4 \nu +3)}{\nu^2+1}$ over the real numbers.

Comment: Thank you for these details. Concerning (iii), this equation obviously has infinitely many solutions in real numbers. Apparently, you meant rational numbers instead. If so, how do you get $\nu=-2$?

Comment: I meant that we cannot solve it in $\mathbb{Q}$ for both $\mu$ and $\nu$ at the same time, but you get also solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. Now, since every rational number is also a real number, let us assume that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, we just need to check $5 \mu^4 (4 \nu + 3) + 3 (\nu^2 + 1) = 0$ and so we have to disregard the two general solutions $n=\dots$ by https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5+m%5E4+%284+n+%2B+3%29+%2B+3+%28n%5E2+%2B+1%29+%3D+0 and my previous statement follows.

Comment: My question was why those two solutions are "the **only** two solutions" (and in what sense: in $\mathbb Q$?). I don't see an answer to that so far. As I wrote previously, "this equation obviously has infinitely many solutions in real numbers." I don't know what exactly you are saying "we just need to check", and what and why "we have to disregard".

Comment: I've already posted the link to the general solutions I am referring to. As I said above, you just have to check that both $\frac{1}{3} (-10 \mu^4 - \sqrt{100 \mu^8 - 45 \mu^4 - 9})$ and $\frac{1}{3} (-10 m^4 + \sqrt{100 \mu^8 - 45 \mu^4 - 9})$ cannot be rational, and so it is since $\nexists \mu \in \mathbb{Q} : \sqrt{100 \mu^8 - 45 \mu^4 - 9} \in \mathbb{Q}$. That's it.

Comment: You wrote: "you just have to check that both [...] and [...] cannot be rational". And how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is to provide some details on the [answer by Alexandre Eremenko](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442617/36721), who referred to [Ritt's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501211-X/).

On p. 25 of Ritt's paper we find this: "Summarizing the foregoing results, we see that the only polynomials of prime degree whose inverses can be expressed in terms of radicals are those of the forms $a(w+b)^n+c$ and $af_n(bw+c)+d$, where $\cos nu=f_n(\cos u)$." (Note that Ritt only considers irreducible polynomials.)

In our case, the polynomial $P(z):=z^5-3z-A$ is irreducible and of degree $n=5$. So, here $f_n(t)=f_5(t)=t (5 - 20 t^2 + 16 t^4)$.
Expanding $a(z+b)^5+c$ and equating the resulting coefficient of $z^4$ to that of $P(z)$, we see that then necessarily $b=0$, so that $z^5-3z-A=az^5+c$ for all $z$, a contradiction. Similarly, expanding $af_5(bz+c)+d$ and equating the resulting coefficient of $z^4$ to that of $P(z)$, we see that then necessarily $c=0$, and then necessarily $b=0$, so that $z^5-3z-A=d$ for all $z$, a contradiction.

So, roots of $P(z)=z^5-3z-A$ cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. Therefore, according to [Timothy Chow's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442656/36721), roots of $P(z)=z^5-3z-A$ cannot be expressed in terms of "the logarithm, the exponentials, and the other meromorphic functions in the complex plane".

Comment: The positive root of $x^5-3x+8$ is a constant, therefore it is an "elementary function". The question is meaningful only if you permit a parameter in your equation (as you did in your original question) and asking whether a root is an elementary function of this parameter. Of course you may ask whether this constant is an element of a solvable extension of the field of rational numbers, but I don't think that Ritt's theorem addresses this.

Comment: Yes, the distinction between an equation with a parameter and an equation without parameters is important. With a parameter, one is asking about EL *functions*. Without a parameter, one is asking about EL *numbers*. Even simple questions about EL numbers tend to be hard, unless one assumes Schanuel's conjecture. Analogous questions about EL functions are more tractable, and can usually be answered unconditionally.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Thank you for your comment. This should now be fixed.

Comment: @TimothyChow : Thank you for your comment. This should now be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

*remark*
Let's consider $16 X^5 - 20 X^3 + 5 X = A$ for $A \ge 1$.  Note it has unique positive solution
$X = \cosh(\operatorname{acosh}(A)/5)$, which is "elementary" in our sense since
$$
\cosh x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
\\
\operatorname{acosh}(x) = \ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\,\right) .
$$

SO ... any solution of the OP that claims "not elementary" should be compared to this example and see if it also shows this one is not elementary.

Comment: If you write the solution as $X=\frac12(\sqrt[5]{A+\sqrt{A^2-1}}+\sqrt[5]{A-\sqrt{A^2-1}})$, it makes the polynomial visibly solvable in radicals. Thus, it is consistent with the other answers saying that solutions of *non-solvable* polynomials are not elementary.